# Dimension of a set of solutions of linear homogeneous equations with vectorial variables

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A=[a_{ij}]$ be a $r \times n$ be a scalar matrix of rank $r$.
Let us consider the homogeneous system of linear  equations
$$
a_{11}x_1+a_{12}x_2+...+a_{1n}x_n=0 
$$
$$
...
$$
$$
a_{r1}x_1+a_{r2}x_2+...+a_{rn}x_n=0  
$$
with variables $x_1,...,x_n$ from a linear space $X$.
What is dimension of the set of solutions of that system?
I suppose that $n-r$ But, I could prove only the case $n=r$.

(Here. we take an arbitrary $f\in X'$ and we obtain
the system Cramer system
$$
a_{i1}f(x_1)+a_{i2}f(x_2)+...+a_{in}f(x_n)=0 (i=1,...,n)
$$
thus $f(x_1)=...f(x_n)=0$. Since $f$ was arbitrary, hence $x_1=...=x_n=0$. )

Thanks

Comment: A "scalar matrix" is a scalar multiple of the corresponding identity matrix. Do you mean that?

Comment: Either way, you are looking for the [rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem)

Comment: @Steve 53, If $X$ is a linear space over a field  $K$ then $A$ is an arbitrary $r\times n$  matix of rank $r4 with coefficients from $K$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $r \leq n$ as $A$ is rank $r$ and $r\times n$.
If you write it out, your system of equations is simply
$$A\pmatrix{x_1\\x_2\\\vdots\\ x_n} = 0$$
Clearly $A(X) \subseteq X$ as linear spaces contain all linear combinations of their elements. Notice how therefore $B: X^n\to X, u\mapsto Au$ is a linear transformation: for all $u,v \in X^n, k\in K$ you have

- $B(u+v) = A(u+v) = Au+Av = Bu+Bv$
- $B(ku) = A(ku) = kAu=kBu$

The matrix representation of $B$ has rank $\text{rank}(A)\dim(X)=r\dim(X)$:

- your original system of equations has $r$ independent rows (as $A$ has rank $r$)
- when writing $B$ as a system of equations, for each of your original equations, you need $\dim(X)$ equations: one for each variable in the respective $x_i$
- all the resulting equations will be linearly independent. Each of the brackets below correspond to $\dim X$ many pairwise orthogonal subspaces, and you have $r$ brackets. If you changed the basis of $K^n$ such $A$ has orthogonal rows (which you could do as $\text{rank}(A) = r$) then all rows of $B$ would be orthogonal. So $\text{rank}(B) = r\dim(X)$, as change of basis preserves rank.

Intuitively, I just substituted $x_i = [x_{ij}]$ into your original system of equations and wrote it out line by line to get $B$:
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
a_{11}x_{11}+a_{12}x_{21} + \cdots + a_{1n}x_{n1} &= 0\\
a_{11}x_{12}+a_{12}x_{22} + \cdots + a_{}x_{n1} &= 0\\
\vdots\\
a_{11}x_{1\dim(X)}+a_{2}x_{2\dim(X)} + \cdots + a_{1n}x_{n\dim(X)} &= 0
\end{array}
\right.
$$
$$\vdots$$
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
a_{r1}x_{11}+a_{r2}x_{21} + \cdots + a_{rn}x_{n1} &= 0\\
a_{r1}x_{12}+a_{r2}x_{22} + \cdots + a_{}x_{n1} &= 0\\
\vdots\\
a_{r1}x_{1\dim(X)}+a_{2}x_{2\dim(X)} + \cdots + a_{rn}x_{n\dim(X)} &= 0
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Your set of solutions is therefore the nullspace of the matrix $B$, which by the [rank-nullity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem) theorem has $K$-dimension
$$\dim(X^n)- \text{rank} (B)=n\dim(X)-r\dim(X) = (n-r)\dim(X)$$

Your system of equations in vector variables was just impersonating a larger equation in scalar variables :)

Note that when $n=r$ you have $(n-r)\dim(X)=0$ coinciding with your solution $n-r=0$. To see why $n-r$ would fail otherwise let $n=2, r=1, X=K^2$ and $A=\pmatrix{1 & 1}$ to find solution set
$$\left\{\left(\binom{x}{y},\binom{-x}{-y}\right) | x,y \in K
\right\} = \text{span}\left(\left(\binom{1}{0},\binom{-1}{0}\right),\left(\binom{0}{1},\binom{0}{-1}\right)\right)$$
of dimension $2=(n-r)\dim(X) \neq n-r$.
Observe here $B$ is
$$B=\pmatrix{1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0& 1 & 0 & -1}$$
of rank $2=r\dim(X)$ as expected.

Comment: Basically $B=[I_{\dim(X)}a_{i,j}]$. where $1\leq i \leq r\dim(X), 1\leq j \leq n\dim(X)$ and $I_{\dim(X)}$ is the $\dim(X)\times\dim(X)$ identity matrix.

Comment: Steve, thank you very much.